# How to use spark.addFile in SparkR to install a package on the worker nodes?

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

In Spark 2.1, there is a new capability to install third-party packages on the worker nodes using `spark.addFile`. This function adds a file or directory to be downloaded with the Spark job on every node. Then `spark.getSparkFiles(fileName)` can be used to find its download location. The documentation can be found [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/index.html).

I was not able to install any packages on the workers in SparkR shell. Does anybody know how it can be done?

For instanceI want to install foreach packages on all the workers as below:

```
sparkR --master yarn --deploy-mode client
```

Then:

```
spark.addFile('foreach_1.4.3.tar.gz')
df <- as.DataFrame(faithful)

result <- gapplyCollect(
    df,
    "waiting",
    function(key, x) {
        y <- data.frame(key, max(x$eruptions))
        colnames(y) <- c("waiting", "max_eruption")     
        install.packages(spark.getSparkFiles('foreach_1.4.3.tar.gz'),repos=NULL,type='source')
        library(foreach)
        y
    })
head(result[order(result$max_eruption, decreasing = TRUE), ])
```

However, as part of the error messages I see:

```
Error in invokeJava(isStatic = TRUE, className, methodName, ...) :
  No connection to backend found. Please re-run sparkR.session()
```

And when I comment `install.packages(spark.getSparkFiles....` line I get this error:

```
Error in library(foreach) : there is no package called âforeachâ
```